# Multiple variables into one textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I' am trying to import multiple js variable values into one textbox in html, but  only the first variable gets displayed.

Is there a way to display all variables (two floats, two strings) in one textbox, or should I search an other solution?

```
document.getElementById('outputbox').value = lengthFixed;  
document.getElementById('outputbox').value = widthFixed;
```

Comment: Please add a code example.

Comment: You have to concatenate variable values first then assign to textbox;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your variables into one and then put it into a textbox.

Javascript

```
var a = "String a";
var b = "String b";
var c = 3;
var d = 4;

var buffer = "" + a + b + c + d; //"" to make sure it is a string

var textBox = document.getElementById('textBoxHtml');
textBox.value = buffer;
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="tb1" id="textBoxHtml" />
```

Comment: var buffer = "" + a + b + c + d; is better so you don't accidentaly add numbers.

Answer (score 1):

JS : //assign anything to your variable and they would display how ever u want.

```
var lengthFixed = 12;
var widthFixed = 17;
document.getElementById('outputbox').value = ""+lengthFixed+widthFixed;
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="outputbox" id="outputbox" />
```

JS FIDDLE :

https://jsfiddle.net/patelnirpendra/31srxt7m/